# Getting query results whether or not rows contains SELECT field

Tags: php, mysql

The query below returns rows that have both `loginid` and `ip2` in the `bumps` table.

All rows in the `bumps` table have `ip2`, but only some have `loginid`.

How can I get the query below to return `ip2` for all rows and `loginid` for the rows that have `loginid`?

```
$sqlStrend = "SELECT e.loginid, e.time, l.username, e.ip2
      FROM bumps e
      JOIN login l ON e.loginid = l.loginid
     WHERE e.submissionid = '$submissionid' 
  ORDER BY e.time DESC
  LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than an `INNER JOIN` (implied by `JOIN`), you just need to change this to a `LEFT JOIN`, which returns all rows on the left-hand table and those related or `NULL` where rows in the related table do not exist.

```
SELECT e.loginid, e.time, l.username, e.ip2
FROM bumps e
LEFT JOIN login l ON e.loginid = l.loginid
WHERE e.submissionid = '$submissionid' 
ORDER BY e.time DESC
LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage
```

Review the different `JOIN` types in [this excellent Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) or [Jeff Atwood's Visual Explanation of Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are actually most of the way there. To get all the rows from bumps and the rows for login that exist you want a [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp):

```php
$sqlStrend = "SELECT e.loginid, e.time, l.username, e.ip2
      FROM bumps e
      LEFT JOIN login l ON e.loginid = l.loginid
     WHERE e.submissionid = '$submissionid' 
  ORDER BY e.time DESC
  LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```